# Where are app data files stored for SwiftUI preview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

When I run an app in XCode simulator the application support directory for it is found in:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/425816A6-9CE8-4884-9D74-B8246D3BA2C5/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/729EDADB-CD24-4DFE-A3A4-C378C5743803/Library/Application%20Support/
```

But where is the Application Support directory located for when I use the canvas preview for a SwiftUI file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code like below:

```
struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
            .onAppear {
            let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationSupportDirectory, 
               .userDomainMask, true)
            print("Preview in: \(paths)")
        }
    }
}
```

generates (user home replaced with ~):

```
Preview in: ["~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/DF93C244-90C0-4AED-887C-316CE2CEFC21/data/Containers/Data/Application/3372351E-A38D-40DD-9F1E-A58A2B30A2AB/Library/Application Support"]
```

Comment: This comes in handy when trying to view managed objects in Preview. I found that the `print` command doesn't write to the debugger. Had to put a break-point in that line and then `po paths`